# how to create a loading screen for sprite-kit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to create a loading screen which can actually load the whole project in Xcode.
I have no idea for now how to do it. Hope you can help.

Comment: I think you should work on loading the project first. Then if it takes more than a second you can start working on a loading screen.

Comment: Create a scene, put a sprite on it, done. I assume it's more than that though. What exactly is it you don't know how to do?

Answer (score 1):

I am taking a guess that you might be referring to loading one or numerous SKTextureAtlas. If so, then you can try this code:

```
NSLog(@"start loading...");
SKTextureAtlas *atlas1 = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:MyAtlas_1];
SKTextureAtlas *atlas2 = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:MyAtlas_2];
SKTextureAtlas *atlas3 = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:MyAtlas_3];
[SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: atlas1, atlas2, atlas3, nil] withCompletionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"loading done...");
        // loading is done so do whatever you need to here...
    }];
```